# Can "libc" be moved to another system by just re-compiling?

Tags: c, linux

Can the C library libc be moved from one system to another by just re-compiling it?

Comment: There no true one single "libc". But if you're thinking of the [GNU C library (glibc)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (which admittedly is the most common implementation on desktop and server Linux systems) then how do you think just about any distribution handles it? They typically get the original source, apply one or more patches, and then build for distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot move `libc` by just recompiling.

The core part of the operating system (called the kernel), manages things like threads, processes, memory management, drivers, thermal sensors, and other vital things. `glibc` uses the Linux kernel for parts of the standard that require system calls.

You'd need to modify it for your system before compiling it. Or, if you are using the Linux kernel, you'd just need to cross-compile the Linux kernel and `glibc` for your target.